# vb.net arcobjects check if topology has error

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, topology

I follow the esri example for validating topology, is it possible to tell whether topology error exists? The code I use:

```vb
    ' Step 1 - access a topology
    Dim topoUiD As UID = New UIDClass
    topoUiD.Value = "esriEditorExt.TopologyExtension"
    Dim m_application As IApplication = My.ArcMap.Application
    Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD), ITopologyExtension)  'original code from esri
    Dim topology As ITopology

    topology = CType(topologyExt.CurrentTopology, ITopology)
    MsgBox("successfully access current topology")

    ' Step 2 - Finding topology errors
    Dim geoDS As IGeoDataset = CType(topology, IGeoDataset)
    Dim errorContainer As IErrorFeatureContainer = CType(topology, IErrorFeatureContainer)
    Dim eErrorFeat As IEnumTopologyErrorFeature
    eErrorFeat = errorContainer.ErrorFeaturesByRuleType(geoDS.SpatialReference, esriTopologyRuleType.esriTRTLineCoveredByLineClass, Nothing, True, False)
    Dim topoError As ITopologyErrorFeature

    ' check the eErrorFeat length to determine whether has error
    topoError = eErrorFeat.Next
    MsgBox("check topology errors.")
```

I am using vs 2012 and arcmap 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this line of code executes:

```vb
topoError = eErrorFeat.Next
```

`topoError` will get set to Nothing if there are no errors. This would tell you that no errors existed, so you could use logic something like:

```vb
If topoError = Nothing Then
    ' No errors, skip processing
Else
    ' At least one error exists do something...
End If
```

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, thanks a lot, have already updated my code. But I find a strange thing of my vb.net arcobjects validate topology function. Since it is another question, I will open a new question.